# Hostname Validator with Annotation Builder

Tags: zend-framework2

I am currently using the Form Annotation builder with Zend Framework 2 (Latest 2.3.2).

I have a single form validator which does not want to play nice and I cannot find any example documentation on how to make the Hostname validator work properly when allowing `local` hostnames.

Here is a code snippet of the validator in question:

```
/**
 * @Form\Type("text")
 * @Form\Required(false)
 * @Form\Options({"label":"name"})
 * @Form\Attributes({"id":"name"})
 * @Form\Filter({"name":"stringtrim"})
 * @Form\Filter({"name":"stringtolower"})
 * @Form\Validator({"name":"stringlength", "options":{"min":"1", "max":"254"}, "break_chain_on_failure":"true"})
 * @Form\Validator({"name":"hostname", "options":{"allow":"\Zend\Validator\Hostname::ALLOW_LOCAL"}, "break_chain_on_failure":"true"})
 * @Form\Validator({"name":"CompanyDns\Validator\DnsName", "break_chain_on_failure":"true"})
 */
public $name;
```

When the form attempts to validate using a local name I am getting the validators response of:

`The input appears to be a local network name but local network names are not allowed`

I am following the manual http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.form.quick-start.html#using-annotations

Any ideas what I am missing or can do to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that when using the Annotation Builder additional Hostname::* features do not get passed as one would expect.

So this line:

```
@Form\Validator({"name":"hostname", "options":{"allow":"\Zend\Validator\Hostname::ALLOW_LOCAL"}, "break_chain_on_failure":"true"})
```

Should actually read:

```
@Form\Validator({"name":"hostname", "options":{"allow":"4"}, "break_chain_on_failure":"true"})
```

If you look at the Hostname Validator class the `4` represents the `ALLOW_LOCAL` of the validator.

This should resolve the problem for you.